# Unexpectedly getting different standardized data with sklearn StandardScaler

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am getting different standardized values using two scalers built ont he same dataset using scikit-learn's standardScaler class.

I have built a StandarScaler object using Scikit-learn on a training data set with 52 features. Let's call it Scaler1. I then used that scaler to standardize the training data set and learn different models on the standardized data. This led to a best model with selected features (26 out of 52). In order to implement a predictor class that uses the model: (1) I grabbed only columns form the original (non-standardized) data set that correspond to the 26 selected features; then (2) I created and saved (with joblib) a new StandarScaler object by fitting the newly created data set. Let's call it Scaler2. Below is a simple outline of my implementation.

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.set_params (**parameters)
scaler.fit(data)
joblib.dump(scaler, destination)
```

Contrary to my expectation, when trying to standardize the original data set, Scaler2 gives me different values for the same data points, compared to Scaler1, for each of the 26 features.Is that behaviour normal? Doesn't the standardization happen independently for each row? How can I fix this issue?

Best,
Yannick

Answer (score 1):

This issue was fixed. It is important to make sure the order in which the features are processed remains the same, as the standardizer model does not appear to have the names of the features saved.